# Trying to make my casino code run until all money is gone

Tags: java

So I had to make this casino program for homework and I have it all finished except for one small step.  I need my game to continue running if i win with my new amount of money. (if this makes any sense)

```
public class CasinoSlot{
  public void play(){
    int coins=(int)(Math.random()*20+5);
    System.out.println("You have "+coins+" coins.");
    int bet=(int)(Math.random()*4+0);
    System.out.println("You bet "+bet+" coins.");
    if (bet==0){
      System.out.println("Please try again.");
    }
    else{
      int rem=coins-bet;
      if (bet>0){
        System.out.println("You have "+rem+" coins remaining.");
      }
      int d1=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
      int d2=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
      int d3=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
      int same=(10*bet), rsame=(same+rem);
      int same2=(7*bet), rsame2=(same2+rem);
      int oddeven=(5*bet), roddeven=(oddeven+rem);
      int lose=(-1*bet), rlose=(lose+rem);
      System.out.println("You rolled: "+d1+", "+d2+", "+d3);
      if(d1==d2 && d2==d3){
        System.out.println("You win "+same+" coins. You now have "+rsame+" coins remaining.");
      }
      else if(d1==d2 || d2==d3 || d1==d3){
        System.out.println("You win "+same2+" coins. You now have "+rsame2+" coins remaining.");
      }
      else if((d1%2==0 && d2%2==0 && d3%2==0) || (d1%2!=0) && (d2%2!=0) && (d3%2!=0)){
        System.out.println("You win "+oddeven+" coins. You now have "+roddeven+" coins remaining.");
      }
      else{
        System.out.print("You lose "+lose+" coins. You now have "+rlose+" coins.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So basically if i roll all the same and win 40 so i now have 45 i want the code to run again with the 45 coins opposed to the random number of coins i had before

Comment: Do you understand this code?

Comment: First, learn about indentation.

Comment: Second, learn about [while loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Yeah I understand what i coded so far, I know a little about while loops but i didnt know you could use one for this program. Sorry I have a horrible CS teacher

Comment: Learn a more about loops, little won't work.@Justin

Answer (score 1):

Basically like people mentioned you need to write a loop. There are a couple of different types, [check them out](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

I would use a while loop though the syntax is very easy:

```
while(someCondition) {
    // execute some stuff
}
```

I took the liberty of looking at your code as you say that your CS teacher is not to good (I'm sure he actually has lots of valuable information though) because I'm bored and currently have nothing to do (at least that I want to do).

A pet peeve of mine is people writing code without maintainability in mind, I know you're a beginner so it's great to pick up this habit early on, I wrote a piece of code for you to see what this application would look like if written by me (I think of myself as an average Java programmer) in the hope of inspiring you to see what you can achieve with your app.

I based my app on your app.

You'll notice that I use lots of methods that are designed to prevent me from writing the same code over and over again, for instance `generateNumber(int max, int min)`, `determineResult(int bet, int payout)` and `play(game game)`. I can actually define rules for lots of different games and reuse the same code so allow users to play the game, currently I defined just 2 to demonstrate this.

Also by encapsulating functionality of different parts of the program in methods I can easily change them to something new, have different games pointing to different methods or even build a new game up from a group of other games' methods to create something really complicated without even needing to write more code (or at least that's the idea).

```
/**
 * 
 * The Casino Slot game
 * 
 */
public class CasinoSlot {

    /** The payout multiplier for the THREE_DICE_SAME_3 result */
    private static final int PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_SAME_3 = 2;
    /** The payout multiplier for the THREE_DICE_SAME_2 result */
    private static final int PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_SAME_2 = 1;
    /** The payout multiplier for the THREE_DICE_ODD_EVEN result */
    private static final int PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_ODD_EVEN = 1;

    /** The payout multiplier for the FIVE_DICE_SAME_5 result */
    private static final int PAYOUT_FIVE_DICE_SAME_5 = 10;

    /** The payout multiplier for the LOSS result */
    private static final int PAYOUT_LOSS = 0;

    /** The player's coins */
    private int coins;

    private enum game {
        THREE_DICE, FIVE_DICE
    }

    /**
     * The program entry point
     * 
     * @param args
     *            The program args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CasinoSlot();
    }

    /**
     * The CasinoSlot constructor
     */
    public CasinoSlot() {
        coins = generateNumber(20, 5); // generate initial coins
        while (coins > 0) { // game loop
            chooseGame();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Chooses which game to play
     */
    private void chooseGame() {
        if (coins < 10) {
            // desperate times...
            play(game.FIVE_DICE);
        } else {
            play(game.THREE_DICE);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Generates a random number between max and min or zero if max-min <= 0
     * 
     * @param max
     *            The max number
     * @param min
     *            The min number
     * @return the random number
     */
    private int generateNumber(int max, int min) {
        if (max - min <= 0)
            return 0;
        return (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    /**
     * Determines the payout
     * 
     * @param bet
     *            The bet
     * @param payout
     *            The payout multiplier
     * @return The payout
     */
    private int determineResult(int bet, int payout) {
        int win = bet * payout;
        System.out.println("You win " + win + " coins.");
        return win;
    }

    /**
     * Called per play cycle of the application
     */
    public void play(game game) {
        System.out.println("You have " + coins + " coins.");
        int bet = generateNumber(4, 0); // determine bet
        System.out.println("You bet " + bet + " coins.");

        // analyse bet
        if (bet == 0) { // no bet
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
        } else if (coins - bet < 0) { // can't bet
            System.out.println("You don't have that much!");
        } else { // bet placed
            coins -= bet; // update balance

            // determine game
            switch (game) {
            case THREE_DICE:
                System.out.println("Play 3 dice...");
                coins += playThreeDice(bet);
                break;
            case FIVE_DICE:
                System.out.println("Play 5 dice...");
                coins += playFiveDice(bet);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    /**
     * The Three Dice rules
     * 
     * @param The
     *            bet amount
     * @return The result
     */
    private int playThreeDice(int bet) {
        int result;

        int d1 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d2 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d3 = generateNumber(6, 1);

        System.out.println("You rolled: " + d1 + ", " + d2 + ", " + d3);

        if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3) {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_SAME_3);
        } else if (d1 == d2 || d2 == d3 || d1 == d3) {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_SAME_2);
        } else if ((d1 % 2 == 0 && d2 % 2 == 0 && d3 % 2 == 0) || (d1 % 2 != 0) && (d2 % 2 != 0) && (d3 % 2 != 0)) {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_THREE_DICE_ODD_EVEN);
        } else {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_LOSS);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * The Five Dice rules
     * 
     * @param The
     *            bet amount
     * @return The result
     */
    private int playFiveDice(int bet) {
        int result;

        int d1 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d2 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d3 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d4 = generateNumber(6, 1);
        int d5 = generateNumber(6, 1);

        System.out.println("You rolled: " + d1 + ", " + d2 + ", " + d3 + ", " + d4 + ", " + d5);

        if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3 && d3 == d4 && d4 == d5) {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_FIVE_DICE_SAME_5);
        } else {
            result = determineResult(bet, PAYOUT_LOSS);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: In fact I would make a game `interface` that all my game types implemented and then have all my game rules put into their own classes too. Then the sky is the limit for creating game types to run through the app.

Comment: But the purpose of the code above was to demonstrate readable and maintainable code. not how I would actually put your app into production.